# jQuery modal plus drag and drop

Tags: jquery, dialog, draggable, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery to build a magentic refrigerator game where you create sentences from the word bank.  I have a list of 90+ words.  I would like for the user to be able to open the word bank in a draggable modal and then drag each word from the modal to the main content div.  The issue I am having is that I can only keep the words inside the modal.  When I go past the modal border the draggable is constrained to the modal. Any help would be appreciated.  I tried

$("#draggable").draggable({ containment: '#demo' });

With demo being the main content div and the modal div id is "dialog"

Answer (score 1):

This is one article I wrote a while ago exactly about how to sue draggable and droppable.

it's got code and examples you might find useful on it.

http://www.placona.co.uk/blog/post.cfm/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning

Hope it helps